# Child Indexes in AS3

Tags: z-index, actionscript-3

I've got an app in as3 that at first adds a sort of container to the stage then as you progress through the app it adds and removes children from that container. I wrote a modal function to display errors. When I call on this function it adds all the necessary children to the stage and then fades them in. What I've found is that it places the children on the stage in front of the container, but not in front of the things IN the container. I've tried "setChildIndex" but it doesn't do anything. I've also tried moving the function to the bottom of the page but that also does nothing. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

> What I've found is that it places the children on the stage in front of the container, but not in front of the things IN the container.

This does not seem correct. The way the displaylist is set up, anything in front of the container *will* be in front of all the children of the container.

Are you sure you're adding everything to the correct parent? What makes you think that your modal dialogue is in front of the container? What makes you think that your dialogue is behind the other children of the container?

Comment: the container has a background and I have a lightbox style shade going over it and it seems to get darker, I could be totally mistaken, and it's all behind the container, but I can't figure out a way to get it in front